# How can I translate a "child relationship" reference into an object API name (external software via API)?

Tags: api, custom-report-type, childrelationship

I'm poking around, writing a Python script to fetch ".reportType" XML files for all ReportTypes in an org and then do various things to those files.

First up is figuring out what tables they include.

By parsing the raw XML file, I'm able to easily get output that looks like this:

```
Schools_with_Applicants.reportType:
4 table(s)
['School__c', 'School__c.FancyPackage__Contacts__r.FancyPackage__Applications__r.Transcripts__r', 'School__c.FancyPackage__Contacts__r.FancyPackage__Applications__r', 'School__c.FancyPackage__Contacts__r']
```

And I can see from poking around the web user interface that there is indeed:

- a lookup field to the "FancyPackage__Appli__c" object on the "Trscpt__c" object with a Namespace Prefix of FancyPackage and a Child Relationship Name of Transcripts
- a lookup field to the "Contact" object on the "FancyPackage__Appli__c" object with a Namespace Prefix of FancyPackage and a Child Relationship Name of Applications
- a lookup field to the "School__c" object on the "Contact" object with a Namespace Prefix of FancyPackage and a Child Relationship Name of Contacts

What I actually want as output is:

```
Schools_with_Applicants.reportType:
4 table(s)
['School__c', 'Trscpt__c', 'FancyPackage__Appli__c', 'Contact']
```

That way, it'll be easy to quickly figure out all reports that use the"FancyPackage__Appli__c" so that when we need to quickly add/remove fields from all such reports, it's not such guesswork.  *(Not to mention, I can probably script editing the XML from there.)*

Question is, what's the simplest way, over various APIs Salesforce provides, to get the data I need to do this translation?

I'm sure I could download the XML for every single object in my org, then parse it, setting aside relevant details from lookup & master-detail fields I find therein.  But that seems like a lot of overhead.

Is there a less messy interface I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is going to be tracing the relationship fields through Describe API results. Fortunately, this is very easy to do using the Python `simple_salesforce` module. Once you establish a `Salesforce` object (the connection) you can do

```
 describe = sf.Contact.describe()
```

That result object contains all the field data that you'd normally get from the Describe API. There's a list of fields in `fields`, each field being a Python `dict`.

Each field entry has a `type`, which is `reference` for a lookup relationship, and a list `referenceTo`, which contains the API names of the one or several objects (several in the case of polymorphic lookups) to which the field looks up.

You could take those relationship paths and break them up by the period separator and use those to walk the Describe data and obtain the target Sobject names.

There's also a global `describe()` method you can use to get a list of all the Sobjects in the system for fully dynamic access, and you can instantiate the module's named Sobject proxies dynamically via the `SFType` class.

Experimenting with the describe methods in a Python console can be really helpful because it is a fairly deep data structure.

`simple_salesforce`: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce

Comment: Thanks; that sounds promising.  I did the whole "download every object and parse its XML files" route, and it worked, but that download is SLOW compared to just downloading ReportType XML files, so I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: Describe API is definitely a lot faster than the Metadata API + tons of XML parsing and walking!

Comment: Thanks so much!  Any thoughts, while you're here, about the most efficient way to comb through report definitions themselves?  I have 1,600 reports in the org at the moment (although I could narrow that down somewhat if I could filter them by report type).  Making 1600 "describe" queries seems slow.  There's always metadata-API-downloading them all.  Other thoughts about the fastest way to grab enough detail about applicable (400-1600) reports to parse them for "are X, Y, or Z fields involved in them"?

Comment: If you cache the describes for each object in a dict keyed on object name, it'll be fast. I wouldn't worry too much about optimizing that part of the solution beyond caching.

Comment: As for the reports, I would probably just use the Metadata API. You might be able to use the Analytics API via REST, but I am less familiar with that route and not sure it's any easier - report metadata is always pretty complex.

Comment: Yeah ... so complex I still can't figure out how to do it.  :-)  I see from inspecting an Eclipse package.xml file that to get report XML files, I just need to include the usual types/name/members rows in a package.xml, but I cannot for the life of me find the right documentation online to figure out how to get a list of the things to put in "members."  Been working on this for days...

Comment: I can probably dig up an example `package.xml` for report extraction. You're correct that it works the same way as other metadata types, although report names get prefixed with their folder names.

Comment: I actually found an example `package.xml` -- my problem is figuring out what to query to get a list of the 1600 fully-qualified reports that exist in my org.

Comment: You may want to open a new question on that - there are some fun complexities around report sharing.